# pm2 node js https server is not starting using trusted certificates

Tags: javascript

When I try to start the node js server using pm2 it is working fine for http service of node js but for secure node js server (https) pm2 not starting app.js.

Can someone help me to resolve the problem?

My code is:

```
var options={
    //key:fs.readFileSync('./1ade203feb7ddfa7.pem','utf8', function(error, data){console.log(data)}),
    //cert:fs.readFileSync('./1ade203feb7ddfa7.crt','utf8', function(error1, data1){console.log(error1)})

    //pfx: fs.readFileSync('./gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b')
    
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem', 'utf8'),       
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.crt', 'utf8')

    //requestCert: false
    //rejectUnauthorized: false
}

https.createServer(options,app).listen(4433)
```

Comment: not sure why you are adding an utf8 encoding indication. I'd remove it since it's completely unrelated. Also, pm2 has a very usefull logging system. What errors are you getting?. Just do `pm2 logs #` where # is the id of the row of the server you want to start. You can check the id with `pm2 list`